# How to resolve return modal not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, modalviewcontroller

```
@PostMapping("/api/file/delete")
public String deleteMultipartFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
   try {
      String keyname=request.getParameter("keyname");
      s3Services.deleteFile(keyname); 

      return "redirect:/welcome";
   } catch(Exception e) {
      return "redirect:/welcome";
   }
}
```

Actual result  :

printing "redirect:/welcome " in white page

Expected Result : it redirect to welcome modal.

Comment: You probaby annotated your controller with RestController rather than Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a Java application framework and Spring boot is an evloution of Spring that helps create stand-alone, production-grade spring based application that you can "just run".

Spring boot supports @Controller and @RestController annotation, where 
@Controller annotation indicates that the annotated class is a controller. It is a specialization of @Component and is autodetected through classpath scanning. It is typically used in combination with annotated handler methods based on the @RequestMapping annotation. @RestController is a sibling convenience annotation for creating Restful controllers.

If you created spring boot application having controller with annotation @Controller and you have @GetMapping method which return index.html(file location /src/main/resources/templates/index.html) view page. like code below :-

```
 @Controller
    public class MyController{

     @GetMapping("/")
     public String indexPage(){
      return "index";
      }

     @GetMapping("/index")
     public String routeWithIndex(){
      return "redirect:/";
      }


    }
```

Both function returns index.html page. If you want more knowledge about spring annotation of @Controller and @RestController with examples visit [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers) site or official site about spring.